# How to Auto Tab (Cursor) in @Html.DisplayFor?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

How can I auto tab from one text area to the other?

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713707/how-to-auto-tabcursor-in-html-textboxforor-html-textbox)

Unlike the issue in the given link, I am trying to auto move cursor from one to the next in my view in the search panel.

I am not adding items, therefore I don't have input fields. Instead I am using `@Html.DisplayFor` to bring items from the database and showing them in the table in my home page.

I am using the head of my table as search panels. I have 6 columns and therefore I have 6 search panels. I want to move from one search panel to the next one after adding one character in each of them.

Comment: This feature not available in mvc you should work with jQuery or any others.

Comment: Could you please provide jquery code for this