# Proper way to store JQuery code in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

For the moment I have my JQuery code in `<script>` tag inside View. But like css you usually have your css code in .css file in Content folder(in MVC project).

How is it for JQuery? Are they suppose to be stored somewhere as well?

Comment: Have a look at this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399122/how-to-organize-the-javascript-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications

Comment: You put them in [bundles](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). An MVC project will have a jquery bundle by default when you make a new MVC project.